# Send notification based on column data (calculate date)

Tags: workflow, nintex

I'm using SP2010 and Nintex Workflows, I am unable to use SPD.

I have a calculated column 'Next Review Date' in a document library.

I need to send an email notification on the date on 'Next Review Date' column.

I'm unsure of which actions to add to the Nintex Workflow and how to configure them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Pause until action to pause the workflow until the 'Next Review Date'.  Just configure the action to use the column you created for the 'Review Date'.  Then after the Pause you can use the Send Notification to send a email notification.